# LazyVGrid code behaves differently in different Xcode versions?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was just watching Standord's CS193p (2021 editions)

The instructor shows this as an example of LazyVGrid:

[image]

As you see the spacing is equal in every direction.

Now here is how I see it with the exact same code in Xcode 14.2 (it's the same with 9 cards too):

[image]

I double checked and the code is exactly the same for both of us!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var emojis = ["✈️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "️"]
    @State var emojiCount = 8

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(),GridItem(),GridItem(),GridItem()]) {
                ForEach(emojis[0..<emojiCount], id: \.self) { emoji in
                    CardView(content: emoji).aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                remove
                Spacer()
                add
            }
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }


    var remove: some View {
        Button {
            if emojiCount > 1 {
                emojiCount -= 1
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
        }
    }

    var add: some View {
        Button {
            if emojiCount < emojis.count {
                emojiCount += 1
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
        }
    }
}


struct CardView: View {
    var content: String
    @State var isFaceUp: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
            if isFaceUp {
                shape.fill(.white)
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                Text(content).font(.largeTitle)
            } else {
                shape.fill(.red)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

How is that possible? if Apple just changes the behavior like that, what happens to old apps when running in newer devices?

Also, **how can I set the vertical spacing to be exactly the same as horizonal spacing? (I am aware I can set the vertical spacing like this: `LazyVGrid(columns:..., spacing: 10)`, but that is a fixed amount and not always equal to horizontal spacing depending on the cols)**

[Timed link to the video on Youtube](https://youtu.be/3lahkdHEhW8?t=4828)

## Edit:

Funny enough, removing the `Text()` inside card or adding `.padding()` to it fixes the issue, but I still don't understand why, it is more confusing when you watch the video:

[Link to Video](https://www.veed.io/view/fe8f0f98-a487-4baa-87a6-74866808139e?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Comment: Are you sure the iOS version is the same between the two?

Comment: No, I'm using iOS 16, but the code is exactly the same.

Comment: There are differences in rendering behavior between OS versions.

Comment: @jnpdx He is using iOS 14 and I'm 16. So SwiftUI designs made for iOS 14 would render differently in iOS 16 with the exact same code? I also noticed, when I remove the `Text()` the issue is resolved, or when I add `.padding()` to the `Text()` But the default padding (when no padding() is added) shows smaller than when padding() is added in the preview section. Somehow the padding/margin of the tiny emoji inside ZStack is making the parent rows push eachother. Can't wrap my head around how that is possible...

Comment: "SwiftUI designs made for iOS 14 would render differently in iOS 16 with the exact same code?" Yes, potentially.